# Is there a way to host my asp.net page through visual studio 2013 (globally)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hosting

I'm working on a www page that is gonna communicate with outside server (I need outside service for payment purposes).

I would like to test messages my page is gonna receive from outside server, but I'm not sure how to do it. I can of course run my page in debugging mode using VS 2013 and set up a breakpoint somewhere, but I don't know how to make my page visible on the internet. It is visible on my pc, but I'd like to make it visbie globally. Is that even possible using visual studio? Is there an easy way to accomplish what I need?

I've got a static IP, I've been already hosting an apache server at linux using my machine. The port that vs2013 is using (49434) is already released but still, I can't get it work.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to deploy your site to an outward facing server/machine. This can bedone on IIS or through hosting companies.

Comment: You need to configure your router to forward a port.

Answer (score 0):

your page cannot be "global" in the sense of everyone on the internet can access it unless you deploy it to a machine for such tasks.  I personally deploy to Amazon Web Services, a small micro instance.

Now, if you would like to test to see how your information reacts, you can write a script to interact with it, but i feel you are more or less wanting to run your local host as a outward facing server and then ping it with client requests of sorts.

Any wya you look at it, get a domain name.  Determine if you are going to host it, with port forwarding (i dont reccomend it unless you have good internet and dedicated machines) or using Amazons WebServices and Cloud processing as a deploy point.

Answer (score 0):

If you own a static ip on your pc or not, use dyndns service (free) to create a dns for your machine which comes with dyndns updater to update that when it changes. They will give you a dns over the internet to access your machine with that.

Comment: I'm not sure what dns has to do with my problem. For now, I don't care about the domain. I just want my page to be accessible through IP